# Error Parsing json data python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file which I am parsing in the following way:

```
data = open('DataFile.json', 'r')
data = json.load(data)
```

It works perfectly when I use this code in simple python script but when I run this in a method which calls other functions as well it throws

```
 File "C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/SDP/WebServices.py", line 143, in methodForParsing
    data = json.load(data)
  File "C:\Users\****\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\json\__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\****\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\****\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\****\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have checked on json formatter and other online websites, my json format is correct. I dont't know why it is not working in a method.

Comment: `print(data.read())` just before parsing or `print(data.read()[:100])` if it's too much so that we can see what it looks like.

Comment: It's unlikely that we'll be able to help you solve this problem unless you show us the contents of the file that you are trying to decode...

Comment: Have you double-mega-confirmed that you are reading the correct json file? Printed it, for example?

Comment: @anonymous `loads` is for strings, `load` is correct for files.

Comment: How are you calling it exactly? I suspect you have read from the file-handle which you are passing to `json.load` already and it is returning an empty string.